# How can I populate a vector in reverse?

Tags: vector, rust, indexoutofboundsexception, populate

I've got a vector:

```
let v = Vec<T>::with_capacity(10);
```

I want to populate it with data, in reverse order:

```
let i = 10;
while i > 0 {
    i -= 1;
    v[i] = non_pure_function(i);
}
```

Unfortunately, this panics; when allocating with `Vec::with_capacity`, the actual initial length of the vector is still `0`.

How can I best accomplish this? What if I have no constructor for `T`?

Comment: [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37152766/1233251) seems relevant, but the answers might not be very appealing.

Comment: You may initalize vec like this `[0; 10].to_vec()`

Comment: @ÖmerErden It's not `{integer}`s, though, and I don't have access to the constructor.

Comment: @E_net4theAbusedDownvoter Once again, you've found the duplicate target.

Comment: It would be nice to have something like `reverse_collect`.

Comment: @starblue It's theoretically possible to create such a thing with `unsafe`, though I'm nowhere near clever enough at Rust to do so.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 The point is that somebody clever enough could write it using `unsafe`, then everybody could use it safely. Though I'm not sure this use case is common enough to put it in the standard library.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I Populate a vector in reverse?

You can do it with [VecDeque](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.VecDeque.html):

```rust
use std::collections::VecDeque;

fn main() {
    let mut v = VecDeque::new();

    for i in 0..5 {
        v.push_front(i);
    }

    for item in v {
        print!("{}", item);
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e5fa8333d35426245ed1bce22377e084)

---

Instead of using `VecDeque` you can solve this problem with using array and the iterator:

- Declare an array containing Option types.
- Set array cells with the indexes.
- Iterate over your array.
- Filter your array to eliminate `None` values
- Map the unwrapped values
- Collect them into vector.

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut v = [None; 10];
    let mut i = 5i32;

    while i > 0 {
        i -= 1;
        v[i as usize] = Some(4i32 - i);
    }

    let reverse_populated: Vec<i32> = v
        .iter()
        .filter(|x| x.is_some())
        .map(|x| x.unwrap())
        .collect();

    for item in reverse_populated {
        print!("{:?}", item);
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c1d8dd167e36f050837e91c7c78a523c)

---

> Both output will be: `43210`

Comment: But then I'd have to convert that to a `Vec`.

Comment: Since Vec implements From trait for VecDeque, you can easily convert it to vec.

Comment: But if I'm doing this, couldn't I just populate the vector forwards and then reverse it? Why would this, which requires more memory allocations, be better?

Comment: Converting `VecDeque` to `Vec` will not cause any new allocations. Both of them hold internally `RawVec` and this buffer is passed from one to another. Depending on the current state of `VecDeque` the elements may need to be reordered, which is done by few calls to `ptr::copy`. That is probably faster than reversing order of elements (few big memcpy, vs multiple smallers ones). But of course writing the elements straight to their final position would be best.